# Calling .length() in the for declaration is slower than doing so before the loop?

Tags: java, optimization, for-loop, micro-optimization

In Java code, I think this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    // do a lot of something
}
```

Is slower than this:

```
int length = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // do a lot of something
}
```

Please tell me whether I'm correct.

Comment: What is the type of `s`?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `s.length()`. What is `s`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory the first code sample could be slower because it calls `s.length()` once per iteration. But it's possible that the JVM will optimize the first piece of code for you. Use the simpler approach unless benchmarks show that:

1. You are in a performance critical piece of code.
2. Storing the length in the local variable actually does give a speed up.

Comment: I guess it depends upon what `s` is.  It could of be that `s` is some sort of stack, and that it grows as the loop iterates - in which case an attempt at JVM optimization could actually change the program logic.  The JVM would first have to determine that the `length()` method only refers back to an immutable property - and that `s` itself is at least treated as `final`.

Comment: It should be noted that one should generally write the for loop as `for (int i = 0, length = s.length; i < s; i++)` because a) that limits the scope of the variable more and b) it's an idiom at least in c/c++.